# Pine Script: All three indicators have to confirm trend

Tags: pine-script

My strategies is based on 3 different indicators. As a condition all of them have to be false at least on one candle before the main indicator becomes true. In my example candle 4 does not get a trigger, as indicator 2 was not false on candle 3. Candle 10 is true for the main indicator, as all indicators were false either on candle 8 or 9.

| bar | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| indicator 1 | true | true | false | true | true | false | true | true | false | true | ... | ... |
| indicator 2 | false | true | true | true | false | false | true | true | false | true | ... | ... |
| indicator 3 | false | true | false | true | false | false | true | false | true | true | ... | ... |
| melting indicators | false | true | false | false (not all were false on #3) | false | false | true | false | true | true | ... | ... |

You would help me a lot!

Comment: Can you explain how #2 and #9 are true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need the melting indicator to be `true` when indicators 1-2-3 are `true`, but only if indicators 1-2-3 have been `false` at any point in the previous 2 bars.

This pseudo-code would do that.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

var bool    a = na // indicator 1
var bool    b = na // indicator 2
var bool    c = na // indicator 3
var bool    m = na // melting indicator

m := a and b and c and (not a[1] or not a[2]) and (not b[1] or not b[2]) and (not c[1] or not c[2])

plot(na)
```

Or you could do it with a function, which improves the code readability.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

var bool    a = na // indicator 1
var bool    b = na // indicator 2
var bool    c = na // indicator 3
var bool    m = na // melting indicator

f_check(bool _x) => _x and (not _x[1] or not _x[2])

m := f_check(a) and f_check(b) and f_check(c)

plot(na)
```

Edit 1 in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70702084/pine-script-all-three-indicators-have-to-confirm-trend/70711186?noredirect=1#comment125013580_70711186) :
Example with undefined number of candles

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

var bool    a           = na // indicator 1
var bool    b           = na // indicator 2
var bool    c           = na // indicator 3
var bool    m           = na // melting indicator
var bool    a_triggered = false
var bool    b_triggered = false
var bool    c_triggered = false

// once triggered, keep triggered until reset
a_triggered := not a or a_triggered
b_triggered := not b or b_triggered
c_triggered := not c or c_triggered

// melting indicator will ony be able to be true when conditions are met for a, b, c AND if all triggers have fired since last reset
m := a and b and c and a_triggered and b_triggered and c_triggered

// melting indicator is true?
if m
    // reset triggers
    a_triggered := false
    b_triggered := false
    c_triggered := false

plot(na)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that with an undefined number of candles? It could be 2 candles like in the simplified example above, but there might be 100 or more "false" signals between the "true" trade signal.

Comment: Sure, added Edit 1 to my answer with an example.

Comment: I noticed there was a small error in my code in Edit 1. Fixed it. Changed `a_triggered := not a or a_triggered[1]` to `a_triggered := not a or a_triggered`. Same for `b` and `c`.